# Wrapping a flat plane around a sphere

Tags: objects

What I'm trying to accomplish is to be able to wrap a plane of objects onto a sphere. Think of it as a plane of varying heights. How should I approached this? I've tried using x and y wrap modifiers but it isn't looking correct.

Comment: Do you mean something like what is done in [How to animate morphing a rectangular plane into a sphere](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24043/how-to-animate-morphing-a-rectangular-plane-into-a-sphere)?

Comment: Also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52904/wrap-curve-around-sphere/53172#53172 and: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13898/morph-targets-a-sphere-shape-turning-into-a-cylindrical-unwrapped-sphere-shape/13927#13927 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56919/how-can-i-create-spherical-topology-from-a-2d-image/56976#56976